# Unable to get xpath of span with a particular class

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am unable to get the xpath of the following span element:

```
<span data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;&#125;" class="userContent">This is the third post of this page.</span>
```

I have pasted the xml file at this url:http://pastebin.com/MfXsYSJQ
(Just ctrl+f it). 
I am trying the following xpath:

```
html/body//span[@class='userContent']
```

But its returning null.So why is it so and how should I get it from the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your span is part of a comment. You can not write XPath expressions for the contents of comments.

**EDIT** Further clarification:
Look at your pastbin code, search for the span and look if it is part of a comment. You can simplify the job the the use of xmllint --format. You will see that xmllint will not indent the body of the comment. And your span is part of such an unindented block, which is part of a comment

Comment: Look at your pastbin code, search for the span and look if it is part of a comment. You can simplify the job the the use of `xmllint --format`. You will see that xmllint will not indent the body of the comment. And your span is part of such an unindented block, which is part of a comment `<!-- -->`.

Comment: Ah got it! That solved the problem. But I am surprised to see that it is commented. Its generated using HtmlUnit and works find once I log in to the site.Anyways thats a different issue though. Thanks!!